# assigning a value to factory params from a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this code in my app.factory, `stardate and enddate` are my parameters to complete my request GET

```
app.factory('Incident', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/:path?limit=8&startDate=:startdate&endDate=:enddate&order=orderBy=id', {
        path: '@path'
    }, {
        getIncidents: {
            method: "GET",
            params: {
                path: 'incidents',
                startdate: '@startdate',
                enddate:'@enddate',
            },
            isArray: false
        }
    })
```

and i use this function:

```
app.controller("IncidentIndexCtrl", function ($resource,$scope, Incident, Device, $http, $window) {

    Incident.getIncidents(function (data) {
        $scope.incidents = data._embedded.incidents;
    });

        $scope.substract = function(){   
            substract = document.getElementById("substractValue").value;
                var actualdate = new Date();
                var DD = actualdate.getDate();
                var MM = actualdate.getMonth()+1;
                var YYYY = actualdate.getFullYear();
                var date = new Date();
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - substract);
                var dd = date.getDate();
                var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
                var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
            return console.log('Actual Date: ',actualdate, DD, MM, YYYY,  'Result: ', date, dd, mm, yyyy);
    };
```

input on index.html

```
<input id="substractValue" type="text"><button type="submit" ng-click="substract()">substract</button>
```

but I do not know how to assign the value to Parameters, just i want to know how to pass the values, with that, I can continue working on my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer, pass the parameters as the first argument to your resource action, eg

```
Incident.getIncidents({
    startdate: someDate,
    enddate: anotherDate
}, function success(data) {...});
```

Where `someDate` and `anotherDate` are the string parameters you require.

---

I'd probably restructure your resource like this as you're needlessly adding query variables to the resource URL

```
return $resource('http://incidents-core/app_dev.php/:path', {
    path: '@path'
}, {
    getIncidents: {
        method: "GET",
        params: {
            path: 'incidents',
            limit: 8,
            order: 'orderBy=id'
        },
        isArray: false
    }
})
```